# Javascript smooth window scrolling via scrollbar

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

I would like my webpage to have smooth browser scrolling via the window scrollbar.  That is, if you drag the window scroll bar down and stop, I want the webpage to start scrolling immediately and then decelerate to the stop point.

I've seen implementations of this for mousewheel event, but I want it for scrollbar event as well. For example on this stack overflow question [Enable smooth scrolling for my website in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349245/enable-smooth-scrolling-for-my-website-in-all-browsers) , Jan Turoň gave a good implementation for mousewheel.  I want that same behaviour, but also for scrollbar drag and stop.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the results I want with mcustomscrollbar.  But it took me a while to figure out how to use it within a react project, which I explained here:

[Reactjs: jQuery custom content scroller with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490303/reactjs-jquery-custom-content-scroller-with-reactjs/39938434#39938434)